# How to create a list of checkboxes with corresponding text for each one?

Tags: itext

I am using iText 5.5.4. I have a few multiple choice questions and I would like to produce them (vertically) in a PDF document. I googled a lot and failed to find examples that match my need. The closest one I found is generating a table of checkboxes (without corresponding text for each checkbox). Here is the link:

http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/create-fields-table#1156-checkboxcell.java

Based on this link, I am not able to produce what I need.

Is there any example page that matches my need?

### Update

Here is what I mean visually:

```
How do you like our service?

[a radio button or checkbox] Great
[a radio button or checkbox] Good
[a radio button or checkbox] OK
```

I need to create a fillable PDF form.

Comment: What is the difference between what the example produces and what your needs are? Based on those differences, you may get a better answer.

Comment: My crystal ball is in the shop for repairs and I can't read your mind to find out what matches your need, so I fear I can't help you.

Comment: Amedee and Bruno, thanks for chiming in! I updated to show what I need. Basically, it is similar to a web form. But I need a fillable PDF form. Regards.

Comment: Your edit does not really answer Amedee's and Bruno's questions. To formulate that differently, which aspects of your task are you not able to produce using the techniques from the link you refer to?

Comment: @curious1: I have marked this old question as "needs clarity". Could you add your own close vote? It is most unlikely to get any answers now.